# Pattern Matching Function Arguments

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I've a question regarding this pattern matching in scala:

```
val div: (Double, Double) => Double = {
  case (x, y) if y != 0 => x / y
}
```

I've understand how pattern matching works and its syntaxis in scala, but this expression drives me crazy. How does complier knows that  x and y is an arguments of the function and pattern match on them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rules for this are defined in section [8.5 "Pattern Matching Anonymous Functions"](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions) of the Scala Language Specification. If using an anonymous function with pattern matching, the type must be partially provided. You do that by saying the type is `(Double, Double) => Double`, which is shorthand for `Function2[Double, Double, Double]`.

Now:

> If the expected type is `scala.Function k [S1,…,Sk, R]`, the expression is taken to be equivalent to the anonymous function:
>
> ```
> (x1:S1,…,xk:Sk) => (x1,…,xk) match {
>   case p1 => b1 … case pn => bn
> }
> ```

So no matter what the arity of your function, the pattern match is passed a tuple of the function's arguments, hence you can use the regular tuple extractor syntax.

So your example is short for

```
val div: (Double, Double) => Double = (a, b) => (a, b) match {
  case (x, y) if y != 0 => x / y
}
```

or

```
val div = (a: Double, b: Double) => (a, b) match {
  case (x, y) if y != 0 => x / y
}
```

The *naming* of the extractor parameters `x` and `y` is up to your imagination. You decide how to call the resulting elements of the extractor, you could as well write `case (foo, bar) => ...`